# Replicate JMenu in paintComponent of child

Tags: java, paintcomponent, jmenu

Where would I find the code or how would I create the code to replicate a JMenu in the paintComponent Method using a custom class that extends JMenu?

I have looked through the jdk and cannot find the code for drawing a JMenu in its own class or any of it parents.

I just need the text and icon placement code.

Answer (score 0):

Painting of lightweight Swing components is delegated to the pluggable look-and-feel implementation.  This is why you aren't seeing any painting code in `JMenu`.

In the case of `JMenu` the class responsible for painting would be a child of [`javax.swing.plaf.MenuItemUI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/MenuItemUI.html). Exactly which depends on what L&F you are using.  For example, the Windows L&F would delegate painting of the menu to  `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsMenuUI`

Probably the easiest way to achieve your goal is to look at the implementation for the particular L&F you want to extend, then override the `paintComponent()` method to perform your custom painting.

Take a look at "[Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)" for a decent explaination on how to paint custom components.